# Property 'then' does not exist on type '(dispatch: any) => Promise<any>'.ts(2339)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-typescript

```
 const updateContent = (values: any) => {

    brands.map((brand: any) => {
      if (brand.brandName === values.brand) {
        values.brand = brand.id;
      }
    })
    
    dispatch(updateProduct(currentProduct.id, values))
    .then(response => {
      props.history.push("/products");
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
    });
  };
```

[image]

I use it in js then ok but use it in typescript then got this error.
How to use dispatch().then() in typescript. Please show me. Thanks!!!

Comment: that means the function in dispatch is not returning a promise. can you share that?

Comment: Pls provide us your `dispatch` implementation as well :)

Comment: it just is updateProduct function.

Comment: What `updateProduct` action creator looks like?

Answer (score 2):

This almost always means that you're using the plain version of the `Dispatch` type that comes with React-Redux by default, which does not know that thunks are dispatchable, and thus does not know that dispatching a thunk may return a promise.

You need to tell TS that you're using the specific version of `Dispatch` that includes the thunk middleware.  [Per the instructions in our TS usage guide docs](https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript), the right approach is to infer an `AppDispatch` type from your store, and then create a pre-typed `useAppDispatch` hook with that type:

```
// app/store.ts
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    posts: postsReducer,
    comments: commentsReducer,
    users: usersReducer
  }
})

// Infer the `RootState` and `AppDispatch` types from the store itself
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
// Inferred type: {posts: PostsState, comments: CommentsState, users: UsersState}
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch


// app/hooks.ts
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import type { RootState, AppDispatch } from './store'

// Use throughout your app instead of plain `useDispatch` and `useSelector`
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>()
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector

// features/counter/Counter.tsx
import React, { useState } from 'react'

import { useAppSelector, useAppDispatch } from 'app/hooks'

import { decrement, increment } from './counterSlice'

export function Counter() {
  // The `state` arg is correctly typed as `RootState` already
  const count = useAppSelector(state => state.counter.value)
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch()

  // omit rendering logic
}
```